# Background image showing up too high

Tags: css

I have a `background.png` that for some reason when I insert in body as `background-image` shows up about 30px too high, and 20px too far to the right.

I set:

```
html, body, * {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
```

and that doesn't seem to affect it.

Comment: Can you provide more of your code?

Comment: and meet your best friend http://getfirebug.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify the position for your background using CSS:

```
body {
    background: url(background.png) 20px 30px no-repeat;
}
```

This should re-position your background image to the location you want. The pixel values are the X and Y coordinates respectively.

You can see more on how to work with the background here:

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_background.asp